# Using a ServletRequestListener or Filter to set requestIds in Log4j MDC?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, servlet-listeners

I am trying to use a `ServletRequestListener` to inject a RequestId into the Log4j MDC.  In order to avoid memory leaks, I am clearing my MDC additions in the `requestDestroyed()` method.

I'm using JBoss 4.2.1GA.

However, I'm having a particular issue with it in a very specific use case, in which a Struts Action is redirecting an action.  I can see that the requestDestroyed() method is called, but the redirected action does not call the requestInitialized() method.

```
public class Log4jMDCRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    /**
     * Need to clear the MDC parameters at the end of the request as the thread can be reused by another request
     */
    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent paramServletRequestEvent) {
        MDCUtils.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Inject the necessary trackers into the MDC to use in the log4j loggers
     */
    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent paramServletRequestEvent) {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) paramServletRequestEvent.getServletRequest();

        // generate a random requestId to correlate all logs from the same request
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MDCUtils.setRequestId(requestId);

        MDCUtils.setIP(WebUtil.getRealIP(request));

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            MDCUtils.setSessionid(session.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

In my web.xml:

```
   <listener>
      <listener-class>webapp.listener.Log4jMDCRequestListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

Using fiddler I can see that my browser is issuing a new request to my application after the `requestDestoryed()` method is called, and yet the `requestInitialized()` method is not triggered.  If I look at the object id of the individual request objects being used, I can see that it is the same request id.

Are there any circumstances in which a request object can be reused by the container without triggering the `requestInitialized` method?  Is there any way I can further debug this?

My problem is that the second request ends up with a cleared MDC (after the requestDestroyed is called) and is never reinitialized.

I have attempted to use a Filter instead of a Listener, and I see the same behaviour.  After further analysis, I think I've noticed that this issue is when the container is calling the login page rather than the request itself.

For instance, in my web.xml:

```
  <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <form-login-config>
         <form-login-page>/login.do</form-login-page>
         <form-error-page>/login.do?error=true</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
```

If I try to access any secured page prior to login, the container will redirect me to the login.do form, and in the process will skip the Filter and Listener.  (Putting a breakpoint in my implementation of `ActionCommandBase` and inspecting the call stack, I can see that no filters/listeners are called when the chain is executed.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you tried implementing it with a servlet filter?

Comment: @Kayaman No - I haven't tried a filter.  I figured that a listener was a "cleaner" way to do this.  I realize that this can be done in a filter, but was hoping to understand how/why this was happening in the listener.

Comment: I've done it with a filter, which is pretty much the same code. It's also what [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/chapters/mdc/UserServletFilter.html) provides as sample code, so it's unlikely to be very unclean.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble believing that a `ServletRequest` is entering the system (first servlet or first filter) without a `requestInitialized()` event being triggered.  I might be willing to accept that the redirected request was considered the same as the original request in some way, except that a `requestDestroyed()` event for it was sent.  Thus, if you've characterized the behavior accurately then it sure seems buggy to me.  In that case, your best way forward is probably to find a workaround, such as using a filter instead of a listener as others have suggested.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm a little flabbergasted at this behaviour as well.  I cannot understand how a request object can trigger the `requestDestroyed()` and then continue to be used in the application without triggering a `requestInitialized()`.  I'm even more confused as to how the same object can be reused if it is a different request, unless the server is somehow doing request object caching.  But even at that, it should still be calling the `requestInitialized()` method on reuse.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm in the process of converting this to a filter.  I know it's pretty much the same code.  When I said "cleaner", I thought it would be more apparent as to what the listener is doing.  It also provides a little protection that a dev doesn't one day accidentally move this filter around in the stack given that the listeners are always fired before/after the filter/servlet chain.

Comment: @EricB. JBoss 4.2.1 is pretty old, have you checked for any related bugs?

Comment: Wow... amazingly, I see the same behaviour with a filter!  Something in the `Http11Processor.process()` method in the `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor` class is calling the process again, but skipping the filters and interceptors.

Comment: Servlet containers can and do reuse request and session objects once they go out of scope.  When that happens, the container just cleans them out and fills them with new data.  Indeed, in that case it should be just after that happens that a `requestInitialized` event is broadcast.

Comment: Perhaps you should scrutinize what happens when the redirect is issued.  Maybe your application is doing something wrong at that point (I have no idea what) that is somehow producing some confusion.

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the issue a little; I've added some additional info to the question.  It seems to be whenever it is the container that is redirecting the request to the login form.